# simplepie - link with parameters - parameters are stripped?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

So, I am trying to use SimplePie to parse the RSS feed at:

```
http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/feed/?a=309993-7b86574c044e802f54eb1e51505b49f2
```

Note the a=... paremeter. This feed comes in with an RSS feed that echoes that parameter back:

```
<link>http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/23/thinking-of-selling-dont-overlook-an-outdated-kitchen-buyers-wont/?a=309993-7b86574c044e802f54eb1e51505b49f2</link>
```

But when I request the link from SimplePie, the value is stripped off - the "a=" is still there, but the part ofter the "=" is gone. My code looks like:

```
    $feed_url = 'http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/feed/?a=60500-afb430fdef66a9669353bcb33029bd39';
    $fetch_limit = 5;

    // Load the correct version
    $rss_parser = new SimplePie();

    $rss_parser->set_cache_location('/home/httpd/tmp');
    $rss_parser->set_cache_duration( 3600 );

    $rss_parser->set_feed_url( $feed_url );
    $rss_parser->enable_cache(true);
    $rss_parser->force_feed(true);

    @$rss_parser->init();

    $rss_parser->handle_content_type();

    $rss_items = $rss_parser->get_items(0, $fetch_limit);

    foreach ($rss_items as $post)
    {
        //print "AUTHOR: " . $post->get_author()->get_name() . "\n";
        print "TITLE: " . $post->get_title() . "\n";
        print "LINK: " . $post->get_permalink() . "\n";
        print "\n";
    }
```

Results:

```
TITLE: Thinking of Selling? Don’t Overlook an Outdated Kitchen, Buyers Won’t
LINK: http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/23/thinking-of-selling-dont-overlook-an-outdated-kitchen-buyers-wont/?a=

TITLE: Why Are Mortgage Interest Rates Increasing?
LINK: http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/22/why-are-mortgage-interest-rates-increasing/?a=

TITLE: Winter Is Coming… 5 Reasons to Sell Now!
LINK: http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/21/winter-is-coming-5-reasons-to-sell-now/?a=

TITLE: Homes Across the Country Are Selling Fast! [INFOGRAPHIC]
LINK: http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/18/homes-across-the-country-are-selling-fast-infographic/?a=

TITLE: From Empty Nest to Full House… Multigenerational Families Are Back!
LINK: http://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2016/11/17/from-empty-nest-to-full-house-multigenerational-families-are-back/?a=
```

Are we doing something wrong here?

thanks...

Comment: Can you use [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) for elaborate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe the problem you're facing is due to paramentrs in URL are discarded because the string is not well formed _but here, I'm just guessing..._

Comment: well, I could try, but that would require uploading the 18,000-line SimplePie library in addition to my code. I'll poke around more.